# Where can I find my display scale?

Tags: unity, display, scale-mode

I am trying to get my current display scale from the command line on **Ubuntu 18.04**.

As I can see that there are many different ways of "scaling" (`xrandr`, `gsettings`, text-scaling). The one I'd like see is from `Settings`→`Devices`→`Displays`→`Scale`:

[image: Settings window]

But I cannot find it anywhere. As I mentioned, I tried `gsettings` and `xrandr` but while I can use both to change scaling, they don't hold my current scale, as changed from the settings.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Are you trying to get the information of current display environment or you want to change the resolution?

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I am trying to find current display scale.

Comment: Are you simply trying to make `xrandr` changes persistent across reboots?

Comment: No, I am just trying to get the current display scale as seen in the settings. I just mentioned xrandr and gsettings to show what I have tried already.

Comment: type `xwininfo` in terminal

Comment: I couldn't find any relevant information in the output of that command.